# How to perform a query with where against a public collection in Firestore with Security Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a ruleset in Firestore Security Rules defined in this way:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isUserAllowed(root, metric) {
      return metric != 'private-data' || (metric == 'private-data' && request.auth.token.sub in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(root)/users).data.users);
    }
    
    match /{root}/{doc} {
      allow read:  if root != 'ispd' && doc != 'users';
      allow write: if false;

      match /{metric}/{docs=**} {
        allow read: if isUserAllowed(root, metric);
        allow write: if false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to execute this method from my React application

```
const checkForbiddenEmailDomain = (emailDomain) => {
  const collectionRef = collection(db, 'forbidden-domains');

  const q = query(collectionRef, where('domain', '==', emailDomain));

  return getDocs(q)
    .then(({ docs }) => {
      if (docs.length > 0) {
        const errorToThrown = { message: `The ${emailDomain} domain is forbidden` };
        throw errorToThrown;
      }
    });
};
```

Since I'm accessing `forbidden-domains` which is public I shouldn't have problems, however I always get `Missing or insufficient permission`. I know that there is the section in Firestore documentation where they say something like "Rules are not queries, blablabla", probably the Egyptian hieroglyphs are simpler to understand .

With no jokes, can someone help me? I really don't understand what should I do.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up modifying mu ruleset in this way, and it works:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isUserAllowed(root, metric) {
      return metric != 'private-data' || (metric == 'private-data' && request.auth.token.sub in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(root)/users).data.users);
    }
    
    match /forbidden-domains/{docs=**} {
        allow read;
      allow write: if false;
    }
    
    match /{root}/{doc} {
      allow read: if root != 'instagram-service-private-data' && doc != 'users';
      allow write: if false;

      match /{metric}/{docs=**} {
        allow read: if isUserAllowed(root, metric);
        allow write: if false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```